# How to receive an implicit intent in launcher activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to do something like below example for my launcher activity:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

The problem is that since this activity is also the laucher, I receive launcher intent from `getIntent`.
Also, I can't filter intent in another activity. It's my launcher activity that handles the intent.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if there is a method in your activity then you can check intents mimeType in it using `intent.getType()`.

Comment: `getIntent`? what `getIntent` do you mean?

Comment: @Shivansh Yes I check the mimeType, but I always recieve the `ACTION_LAUNCHER` intent

Comment: @pskink https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()

Comment: ok, so what is the problem that you are receiving the intent from `Activity#getIntent` ?

Comment: @pskink no, I only received the laucher action intent :/

Comment: so what intent are you using when calling `startActivity`?

Comment: @pskink i have set action_send intent filter for my launcher activity and I want this activity to handle the case when i user selects a text and shares it with my app.

Comment: @pskink i tried it, but my activity opened with an `ACTION_MAIN` intent instead of a `ACTION_SEND` intent.

Comment: so how the user shares the text?

Comment: @pskink like from message app, the user long presses the message and the selects share option, there the user finds my app and clicks on it to launch my app activity which handles this intent

Comment: @pskink i guess i mean letting other apps start my app https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: @pskink got it running!

Comment: @Saumya I'm facing the same problem, what did you do to solve it? You should post your solution as an answer to this question :)